# How to remove previous PYTHONPATH completely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonpath

I have two folders `folder1` and `folder2`, both of them have a `config.py` but there is a slightly different in these two folders. `folder1` has a function called `A`, `folder2` has a function called `B`

```
|+--root
    |+-- folder1
        | +--config.py
    |+-- folder2
        | +--config.py
```

Here is how I do it in `ipython` shell in `root` dictionary

```
import sys
sys.path.append(folder1)
from config import A
```

Everything is fine. Then I continue

```
sys.path.remove(folder1)
sys.path.append(folder2)
from config import B
```

There is an error `ImportError: cannot import name 'B'`.

Then I change it a little bit.

```
sys.path.remove(folder1)
sys.path.append(folder2)
from config import A
```

There is no error!! It seems I don't truly remove the `folder1` PYTHONPATH by `sys.path.remove(folder1)`. However, as I check the PYTHONPATH by `sys.path` command. It shows that the PYTHONPATH is `folder2`.

Anyone has a good idea? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you manipulating `sys.path` at all here? Would it not make more sense to do `from .folder1.config import A` or similar? (Whether that precise `import` statement will work depends on other things; but you get the idea.)

Comment: @tripleee This is because the `config.py` is my colleagues code. In his work, he just needs to `import A` or `import B` by `from config import A`

Comment: I don't see how that dictates your choices here.